# Setting window.onbeforeunload to undefined in IE8 causes" not implemented error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, onbeforeload

```
            if(!$('fieldset.quote-step4').hasClass('show')) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    return "Are you sure you want to leave the quote request page? This will reset the form.";
                }
            } else {
                window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
            }
```

I have the above in a script inside of a private function that's causing a "not implemented" error in ie8.

The specific line that causes the error is: `window.onbeforeunload = undefined;`

From what I've read in other questions `window` should be declared as a local variable to fix this issue-- but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone explain this bug to me and a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Um, don't do that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Edited question to show a little more detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
   if($('fieldset.quote-step4').hasClass('show')) {
        return;
   }
   return "Are you sure you want to leave the quote request page? This will reset the form.";
});
```

And it is not the best idea to use DOM1 Handlers when jQuery is already on your page.

Comment: One problem with this solution... Now, Resharper nag me to return something ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` is an event handler; apparently; IE8 doesn't like clearing it.

You can simply set it to a function that doesn't return anything.